# Customizing bash for many servers

Tags: bash, configuration, profile

I work with a few dozen servers. I'd really like to streamline my work, but at the same time I'm a bit reluctant, since it would be a lot of work synchronizing all servers. 
The servers are in different networks so there's little use setting up shared folders.

What options do I have?

Comment: Are you looking for a configuration management solution?

Comment: No. At least I don't think so. I just want to maintain a handful  of aliases and scripts. Preferably in a simple way.

Comment: Then do it the manual way by using one central system, generate ssh keys for the other ones and script your way around copying files. Do the 12 machines have a common place they can go to, or none at all? Otherwise you could put a folder with scripts into an SVN repository for example. And do the rest via ssh.

Comment: There are basically two routes to go, either use a configuration management system like puppet or chef, or create a repository with the configuration files (e.g. using git).

Comment: Please give some more details. How many files do you want to synchronize? Whole directory structures? Just your `.bashrc` or equivalent? You can share folders across different networks by the way.

Comment: OMG! git!! Why didn't I think of that myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach for managing bash_profile on multiple machines. (Designed for mac, but could be adapted to linux)

Put your bashrc (or bash_profile) into a github gist.

Here are mine

https://gist.github.com/spuder/11360447
https://gist.github.com/spuder/730226a73e45f5d3cff5

---

Use a script that does a `wget` of the gists and install them.

https://gist.github.com/spuder/11360474/raw/

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -L https://gist.github.com/spuder/11360447/raw/ > ~/.bash_profile
curl -L https://gist.github.com/spuder/730226a73e45f5d3cff5/raw/ > ~/.bash_ps1
```

---

Install the latest gist with this command

```
curl -L https://gist.github.com/spuder/11360474/raw/ | bash -x
```

---

Once I've run the above command just once on every machine, I then have an alias `bashupdate` which will pull the latest changes.

```
alias bashupdate='curl -L https://gist.github.com/spuder/11360474/raw/ | bash'
```

As far as system management, use the following tools

[puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
[mcollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective)
[serf](http://www.serfdom.io/)
[rundeck](http://rundeck.org/downloads.html)
[ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [dotify](https://github.com/mattdbridges/dotify) to simplify the git workflow and some conditionals in my ZSH and Emacs configs (host name, OS etc.). Also instead of custom scripts I tend to mainly do shell functions nowadays...